# EF Code-First creates some fields ,even I added ForeignKey annotations

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

can any one help me in this ?

Here is my 2 classes

```
class Request
{
    public Nullable<int> BuyCurrencyId {get ; set;}
    public Nullable<int> SaleCurrencyId {get ; set;}

    [ForeignKey("SaleCurrencyId")]
    public virtual Currency SaleCurrency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BuyCurrencyId")]
    public virtual Currency BuyCurrency { get; set; }
}


class Currency
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests1 { get; set; }
}
```

I checked the updated with EF database , and I found out that the EF create `Reqyests`  table like this :

```
SaleCurrencyId int  (Already exists)
BuyCurrencyId  int  (Already exists)
Currency_Id    int  (Added by EF)
Currency_Id1   int  (Added by EF)
```

By this not thing I expect. I thing the last tow columns are not correct and they not be exist.

Can any one help me ?

I am using EF 6 alpha to update the existing database with my generated model by T4.Please keep it in mind that I want to use **data annotations** , not **Fluent API**

Sorry about my bad English

**Update 1** :

I thought if I change the Currency class to this it will resolve my problem , but it did not.

```
class Currency
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [InverseProperty("SaleCurrencyId")]
     public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
     [InverseProperty("BuyCurrencyId")]
     public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Update1 is almost the correct solution, but the parameter of the `[InverseProperty]` attribute must be the navigation property in `Request`, not the foreign key property:

```
[InverseProperty("SaleCurrency")]
public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("BuyCurrency")]
public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests1 { get; set; }
```